# GWT showing low disk space

Tags: gwt

I am new to GWT. Iam using eclipse Indigo along with GWT. The moment I open eclipse and start running a simple program I have created , my system shows low disk space. I can understand it is something related to cache. But dont know how to proceed. The system becomes very slow and not allowing me to work. Again If I close my eclipse and browser , things become normal. Before starting my eclipse I have 2 GB in C. But after some time it become 100 mb and forcing me to clean or close.

What I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-plugin-for-eclipse/issues/detail?id=74) of the Google Plugin for Eclipse.

Workaround:

- avoid relaunching the DevMode too much (you can launch it once and then reload the app at will)
- clean your temporary directory regularly

Comment: I am very new to this. From yesterday only I have started. That why I dont kno abt this. Infact Android Plugins does not create this issue.Any way it works and thanks.